# What to do about AI bots

Tags: discussion

This morning we've had a number of questions, but old and new, that have been answered by what I assume to be some form of AI bot, all by the same (new) user.

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/45728/20219

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/45727/20219

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/45726/20219

The answers aren't bad, per se, but how should things like this be handled? Should the user account be flagged and the answers removed? Should each answer be flagged individually? Should they be left?

This might actually be a wider Stack Exchange issue, but I haven't been that active of late so this is the first I've seen of it.

Comment: I already flagged one of the answers and suggested to the mods that all the answers be purged.

Comment: I'm not super up to speed on the algorithms that make AI bots work, but, I'd assume they pull wording from scraping the internet? That would lead to answers that cite popular myths or misconceptions in the fitness industry. If that is the case, they'd be inaccurate anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Purge the answers and formally ban AI generated content.

AI generated content presents a myriad of problems for the Stack Exchange format. [This Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide/384468#384468) over at meta.se has several well thought out answers that detail why this content should be purged and banned. I won’t go into detail here, just read the responses there. To summarize, there are two points that I think should make it clear that these answers need to just be deleted:

- No citations to authoritative references are given.
- It is a form of plagiarism.

None of these answers we have received have any citations to authoritative sources. This by itself is a reason to apply the “citations needed” post notice, and possibly delete.

Further, *none of these answers are the user’s original work*. This is blatant plagiarism, and not an ounce of original thought went into these responses. This is also, by itself, a reason to delete these answers.

And finally, after reading through them, the answers are incredibly generic and just not very good fits for the questions they were posted on. While the general principles presented seem mostly harmless and consistent with the basics of fitness, they aren’t appropriately tailored to the questions like we would prefer from high quality answers.

These answers should be deleted, and for these reasons, we should formally ban AI generated content as most other sites on the network have already done.

Comment: Cool, that was my feeling too.

Comment: AI-generated content *is* formally banned across the entire network. In the cases where it's easily spotted, we swing the hammer.

Comment: @Alec No, it is not formally banned network wide: ["With due consideration, we've decided no general policy is necessary or helpful at this time."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/674198).

Comment: Ah my bad. I may have misread something that came before Dec 19.